# Not able to test async react-select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-select

I'm trying to test when the user enters some value to the input, and then it fetches some options from API to show and then I select one option out of them then form should have those values.
When I ran `npm test` one test fails for some reason.

My code test code:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import selectEvent from "react-select-event";
import SkillSelect from "../SkillSelect";

test("React select", async () => {
  render(<SkillSelect data={[]} index="1" id="2" />);

  expect(screen.getByTestId("form")).toHaveFormValues({});
  fireEvent.change(screen.getByLabelText("Skills"), {
    target: { value: "java" },
  });
  await selectEvent.select(screen.getByLabelText("Skills"), "java");
  expect(screen.getByRole("form")).toHaveFormValues({
    label: "Javascript",
    value: "javascript",
  });
});
```

Error message:
[image]

Anyone please help me with this!

Comment: You will need to mock result from API first

Comment: Hello Sonu, Can you please tell me how to select an individual Select components? I want to check whether the select element is disabled or not?